# Angular mat-tab-label customization

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I want to remove the grey line below the mat-tab labels. How do I do this?

[image: See sample encircled in red ink]

Comment: It's a matter of some CSS. What have you tried?

Comment: You're using either AngularJS or Angular. Please tag the appropriate version only. They're very different frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Improving @isherwood's answer, really you need put the .css in the `styles.scss` (*) file

```
.mat-tab-header {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

This make that **all** your mat-tab-header get this .css, to avoid this, you can replace the before style by

```
.custom .mat-tab-header {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

And change the .html adding the class

```
<!--see you indicate class="custom" in mat-tab-group-->
<mat-tab-group class="custom">
  <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

(*) you can also use [ViewEncapsulation.None](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation), but this make all the .css in your component is applied to all the aplication

Answer (score 0):

Default styling on [the demo](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview) looks like this:

```
.mat-tab-header, .mat-tab-nav-bar {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}
```

You'll need to implement CSS either at the app or [component](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles) level like this:

```
.mat-tab-header {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```